# Ansible - How do you reference the item currently being looped in another loop

Tags: loops, ansible, nested-loops

I have a variable that looks like (the reality is a lot longer):

```
deploy_dirs:
  conf:
    base: '/etc/projects/'
    subs:
      apache: '/httpd'
      modsec: '/modsec'
      php: '/php'
      haproxy: '/haproxy'
      varnish: '/varnish'
  logs:
    base: '/var/log/projects/'
    subs:
      apache: '/httpd'
      modsec: '/modsec'
      php: '/php'
      haproxy: '/haproxy'
      varnish: '/varnish'
```

Then I have a task that looks like:

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ item.0.value.base }}SOME-OTHER-VAR{{ item.1 }}'
  loop: '{{ deploy_dirs | dict2items | subelements("value.subs") }}'
```

Which I would love to output:

```
/etc/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR/httpd
/etc/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR/modsec
/etc/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR/php
/etc/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR/haproxy
/etc/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR/varnish

/var/log/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR/httpd
/var/log/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR/modsec
/var/log/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR/php
/var/log/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR/haproxy
/var/log/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR/varnish
```

These variables get re-used in various places all over my playbooks, and the structure makes sense to me and seems to be straightforward enough.

I've tried changing the `subelements()` filter in to the `product()` filter (`with_nested` equivalent), but it doesn't seem able to reference the variable from the earlier loop in the same way that the `subelements()` filter can.

Obviously the problem with the above is that `subelements()` needs a list, not a dictionary. I'm unable to convert the `"value.subs"` argument in to a list, as I can't find a way to nest filters like that..?

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this working?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: If I also have:

```
www:
    base: '/srv/www/projects/'
    subs: {}
```

And I just want it to output:

```
/srv/www/projects/SOME-OTHER-VAR
```

Do you know how I can swing the `subs` bit so that it runs and generates the expected result? At the moment it just skips it. i.e., no loop occurs for `www`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your `subs` dict in a list with json_query before using the subelements filter.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.base }}SOME-OTHER-VAR{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: >-
    {{
      deploy_dirs
      | json_query('*[].{base: base, subs: subs.*}')
      | subelements('subs')
    }}
```

Have a look at [jmespath documentation](http://jmespath.org/) for the syntax. json_query is really handy when your data structure gets complex.

This solution will not loop over the elements with an empty `subs` element like the `'www'` map entry in your example and I have no "clean and easy" way to do it in a single task. You can easily have a second task looping over the elements with empty subs => `deploy_dirs | json_query("* | [?!subs]")`

I guess your final goal is not to have debug msg written to the screen. If you really need a single structure to make your final task (e.g. create directories) in a single step, you can populate a var with set_fact and the above techniques and then use it to acheive your real task

```
- name: Get all elements with subs to loop over
  set_fact:
    my_var: >-
      {{
        deploy_dirs
        | json_query('*[].{base: base, subs: subs.*}')
        | subelements('subs')
      }}

- name: Add entries with empty item1 for elements with empty subs
  set_fact:
    my_var: >-
      {{
        my_var
        +
        [[item, '']]
      }}
  loop: >-
    {{ deploy_dirs | json_query("* | [?!subs]") }}

- name: This will be replaced with a real task
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.base }}SOME-OTHER-VAR{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ my_var }}"
```

Comment: This looks interesting... Unfortunately I get `Unexpected failure during module execution.` when using json_query (JMESPath wasn't installed, and I installed it to my pyenv with pip, but now nothing works with it)... Boo.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your pyenv. I still have the example in my tmp with your vars and it gives the expected result. Moreover, I'm over using json_query in prod for a project with particularly complex data structure for weeks without any problems, with either python 2.7 or 3.6+. Running with -vvv should give you more info. I would quickly try to pop a new virtualenv and install only ansible and jmespath to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: In your post, you say that the real data structure is bigger. So the problem could be in the data I don't see. Can you try again only with the example data above ? If it works, then try again with your real data but add the following to the filter: `deploy_dirs | to_json | from_json | json_query.....`. This forces ansible to translate its special string classes to normal string class for json_query. It is normally only needed in special case (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299) but I suspect your data structure contains special replacement vars.

Comment: No, I've fixed it... It was a problem with permissions in my venv. A recursive chown solved the issue (it couldn't access jmespath properly I guess)... There is one more issue I could do with resolving though. I'll update my question with a bit more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updated answer. As there's no obvious way to get the loop to function as desired, I've simply decided to add `_dummy: ''` to the `subs` on `www`... That seems like a cleaner solution and a bit more obvious what's going on. It's a very interesting solution you came up with though, and really demonstrated the power of the `json_query` filter!

Comment: json_query/jmespath is really the swiss knife when working with complex data. Once you start using it, you can't stop :) Have fun.